# I am getting 'Attribute Error' in the following code while tried loading an image, using Python & OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to load image using opencv-python. For that I install python 3.7 and pycharm IDE properly. All settings in pycharm regarding opencv-python, I properly installed.After that, I input this code and run

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg',1)
print(img)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitkey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But this error has been shown:

```
[ 81  68 176]
  [ 81  72 183]
  [ 84  74 188]]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Asaduz Zaman/PycharmProjects/OpenCVExamples/getting_started_with_images.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.waitkey()
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'waitkey'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I donot understand what is the probelm. pls need suggestions

Versions::

Python 3.7
opencv 4.1.26
Pycharm 2019.2.4

Comment: In Pycharm, you could type cv2.wait, then press Tab for a suggestion, it will fill in cv2.waitKey

Answer (score 1):

It should be `waitKey` (upper-case K)

From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey):

> Python: cv2.wait**K**ey([delay]) → retval